# How do I fix my canvas width and height changing every render when I zoom in or out?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm developing a sorting visualization website with my friend (https://tann1.github.io/SortingViz/). We both are fairly new to web development. We're currently facing this issue where if you were to zoom in and press play the canvas window shrinks every render or so. Similarly, if you zoom out it'll expand every render or so as well. You can test this bug out through the GitHub link I attached earlier. There's is definitely something that we're missing and we can't seem to identify it. Some help would be very appreciated.

```js
// JS script goes here
let form = document.querySelector('#nBarsInput'); //# = reference to ID
let sortType = document.querySelector('#algoSelect');

let canvas = document.querySelector('.zdog-canvas'); 
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); 
let nTextBox = document.getElementById('nTextBox');
let nSubmitButton = document.getElementById('nSubmit');
let replayButton = document.getElementById("replayButton");
let nVal = []; //stores the array that needs to be sorted 
let nValUnsorted = [];
let sortSpeed = document.getElementById('sortSpeed');
let unsorted = '#fc90a9'//'#c9751a'
let sorted = '#c94260'
let sorting = '#83BCFF'
//let swapColor = 'red'


nSubmitButton.addEventListener('click', () => {  // generate graph when submit button is clicked
    generateNums(nTextBox.value);
    startSort();

});

function enableInput() {
    nSubmitButton.disabled = false;
    replayButton.disabled = false;
    nTextBox.disabled = false;
    sortSpeed.disabled = false;
}

function disableInput() {
    nSubmitButton.disabled = true;
    replayButton.disabled = true;
    nTextBox.disabled = true;
    sortSpeed.disabled = true;
}
replayButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    nVal = [...nValUnsorted.map(arr => [...arr])];
    //console.log(nValUnsorted);
    startSort();
});


async function startSort() {
    createCanvas(nTextBox.value);
    disableInput();
    switch (sortType.value) {
        case 'Selection Sort': {
            await selectionSort();
            break;
        }
        case 'Insertion Sort': {
            await insertionSort();
            break;
        }
        default: {
            alert("Invalid sort type");
            break;
        }
    }
    enableInput();
}

function generateNums(size) {  // generates array of size ntextBox.value, populated with random numbers
    nVal = [];  // reset array
    nValUnsorted = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        let randVal = Math.floor((Math.random() * 0.55 * canvas.height) + (0.40 * canvas.height));
        nVal.push([randVal, unsorted]);
        nValUnsorted.push([randVal, unsorted]);
    }
    //copy();
}

// do drawing stuff based on given array and N value

function createCanvas(size) { 
    let barWidth = (canvas.width/size);
    let illo = new Zdog.Illustration({  //main parent object of 
        element: ".zdog-canvas",
        centered: false
    });

    let rect = new Zdog.Rect({  // create first bar
        addTo: illo,
        width: barWidth * 0.95,
        height: nVal[0][0],
        color: nVal[0][1],
        fill: true,
        stroke: 4,
        translate: {y: canvas.height - nVal[0][0] / 2, x : barWidth/2}}); 
    illo.updateRenderGraph();
    for(let i = 1; i < size; ++i){  // create rest of the bars by copying the first bar
        rect.copy({
            height: nVal[i][0],
            color: nVal[i][1],
            translate: {y: canvas.height - nVal[i][0]/ 2, x :  (i * barWidth) + barWidth/2}
        });
        //nArr.push(rect);
        illo.updateRenderGraph();
        
         /* text setup*/
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        ctx.font =  (0.50 * barWidth) + 'px monospace';
        ctx.fillText(nVal[i][0], (i * barWidth) + (barWidth/2), 490);
    }


}

async function selectionSort() {

    let curr_pos = 0; // find the position with the lowest current value 
    let temp = 0; // need it for the swap
    for (let i = 0; i < nTextBox.value - 1; ++i) {
        curr_pos = i;
        nVal[i][1] = sorting;
        await pause(sortSpeed.value);
        createCanvas(nTextBox.value);
        for (let j = curr_pos + 1; j < nTextBox.value; ++j) { // finds the lowest relative value in the array
            if (nVal[j][0] < nVal[curr_pos][0])
                 curr_pos = j;
        }
        
        //swap 
        temp = nVal[i];
        nVal[i] = nVal[curr_pos];
        nVal[curr_pos] = temp;

        nVal[curr_pos][1] = sorting;
        await pause(sortSpeed.value);
        createCanvas(nTextBox.value);
        


        nVal[i][1] = sorted;
        if (i != curr_pos) {
            nVal[curr_pos][1] = unsorted;
        }
        await pause(sortSpeed.value);
        createCanvas(nTextBox.value);
    }
    nVal[nTextBox.value - 1][1] = sorted;
    createCanvas(nTextBox.value);
    //console.log(nVal);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {resolve('');})
}


async function insertionSort() {
    let val, j;
    nVal[0][1] = sorted;
    for (let i = 1; i < nTextBox.value; i++) {
        val = nVal[i]; // current value to sort
        val[1] = sorting; //nVal[i][1] = sorting;
        await pause(sortSpeed.value);
        createCanvas(nTextBox.value);
        j = i; // only loop through "sorted" portion
        while (j > 0 && val[0] < nVal[j-1][0]) {  // keep going through sorted portion until correct position is found
            nVal[j] = nVal[j-1]; // shift other values up
            nVal[j][1] = sorted;
            nVal[j-1] = val;
            j--;
            await pause(sortSpeed.value);
            createCanvas(nTextBox.value);
        }

        nVal[j][1] = sorted;
        await pause(sortSpeed.value);
        createCanvas(nTextBox.value);
    }
    return new Promise((resolve) => {resolve('');})
}

function pause(ms) {  // pause execution for a given duration in milliseconds
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => { resolve('') }, ms * 1000);
    })
}
```

```css
/* CSS goes here */
:root {
    --pageColor: #FDB;
    --buttonColor: #c94260;
    --LabelColor: rgba(58, 44, 48, 0.959);
    --textColor: #c94260;
    --disabledColor: #fc90a9;
}

body {
    background-color: var(--pageColor);
    font-family: 'Patrick Hand', cursive;
    font-size: 25px;

}
h1 {
    font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
    font-size: 60px;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 2px 5px var(--textColor);
}

#nBarsInput {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    border: 5px solid var(--buttonColor);
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 30px;
    width: 1100px;
}

#textInput {
    width: 980px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.button {
    background-color: var(--buttonColor);
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 25px;
    margin: 20px 5px;
    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
    box-shadow: 0 5px #999;
}

.button:hover {
    background-color: #83BCFF;
}

.button:active {
    background-color: #83BCFF;
    box-shadow: none;
    transform: translateY(5px);
}

.button:disabled {
    background-color: var(--disabledColor);
}

.inputTextBox {
    padding: 5px 15px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 25px;
    

}

.inputTextBox:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.inputTextBox:disabled 
{
}


label {
    color: var(---LabelColor);
    margin: 5px 15px;
}

main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.zdog-canvas {
    background: var(--pageColor); /*#843b62;*/
    flex-basis: 100%;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Caveat:wght@600&family=Patrick+Hand&family=Source+Code+Pro&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <h1>SORTING ALGORITHM VISUALIZER</h1>
            <div id="nBarsInput">
                <div id="textInput">
                    <div>
                        <label>Enter a sorting speed (in seconds)</label>
                        <input type="text" name="sortSpeed" id='sortSpeed' value="0.25" class='inputTextBox'>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Enter a Value for N</label>
                        <input type="text" name="nBars" id='nTextBox' value="5" class='inputTextBox' required>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                <div id="nBarsButton">
                <select id='algoSelect' class='button'>
                    <option value='Selection Sort'>Selection Sort</option>
                    <option value='Insertion Sort'>Insertion Sort</option>
                </select>
                <input type="submit" value="Go" id='nSubmit' class='button'>
                <input type="submit" value="Replay" id='replayButton' class='button'>
            </div>
            </div>
            <canvas class='zdog-canvas' width='1000' height='500'></canvas>
        </main>
        <script src="./script.js" type="module"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/zdog@1/dist/zdog.dist.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please share your code here in SO and don't just link to a repo.

Comment: Hi @Dominik I only linked the GitHub because there'd be a lot of source code. Also, could you clarify what you mean by SO?

Comment: SO = StackOverflow and it being a lot of code is precisely the reason why the guidelines for asking questions asks you to embed a small sample of the code reduced enough for this format because it forces you to create a more concise sample and means the users of SO are not forced to read through 100s of lines of code.

Comment: I see thanks for clarifying so much. I'm new to posting on SO and I will definitely keep what you said in mind for my future post if I ever need to ask again. Regardless, both of us are stuck and can't seem to identify where the problem is stemming from. I suspect it has to do with createCanvas function because that is where most of the rendering is taking place.